# Java file not found

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I am calling a file `glassShader.vert` from the following method and it gives me `FileNotFoundException` error

The complicated issue is that  the class `GLGridRenderer` that contains this method lies in the directory `GridLogin` which is in turn inside the package `com.jasfiddle.AmazingInterface`

So to address the directory, it would be `com.jasfiddle.AmazingInterface.GridLogin`

But I don't know how to call shader.vert which is inside GridLogin

```
  public static String readShaderFile(String filepath) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
    try{
        FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
        return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
    }
    finally{
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking `(new File(filepath)).exists()` before trying to process it? It sounds like your problem is related to trying to get a shader file that simply does not exist.

Comment: can't you put the file asset ?

Comment: The name of the class (or its package) has nothing to do with where the file is read from. Is the file packaged as a resource or asset? Or is it supposed to exist somewhere on the SD card?

Comment: It clearly shows in my package that the file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other than raw you can also use asset folder see [link](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/) ....

```
try {
                // get input stream for text
                InputStream is = getAssets().open("text.txt");
                // check size
                int size = is.available();
                // create buffer for IO
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                // get data to buffer
                is.read(buffer);
                // close stream
                is.close();
                            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Only an `Activity` class can call files from assets. Any other class will produce a bug if `InputStream is = getAssets().open("text.txt")` inside them. I am not at all calling it from Activity. In that case I will need to pass in the Context parameter through every class until it gets to my `GLGridRenderer` class

Answer (score 0):

Files that you want to read should not be put in a package. They should be packaged as resources or assets. For instance, with a data file, put it in the `res/raw` folder and give it a legal resource name. Then you can open an input stream if you have a `Context` (such as your `Activity` class or a `View` class).

```
InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filepath);
```

(This would be if you named the file `res/raw/filepath.dat`. You'd probably want a more meaningful name. If you want the name to be a variable, then you can obtain the resource ID using:

```
int resId = context.getResources.getIdentifier(filepath, "raw", context.getPackageName());
```